# No undefined error by eslint for typescript dom types

Tags: typescript

```
type EventType<T> = T extends Window ? WindowEventMap : HTMLElementEventMap
```

I get the error,

```
'WindowEventMap' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)
'HTMLElementEventMap' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `DOM` to `compilerOptions.lib` in the `tsconfig.json` file. It would be like the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      ...
      "DOM",
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [troubleshooting documentation of typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors) has an entry about this:

> The no-undef lint rule does not use TypeScript to determine the global
> variables that exist - instead, it relies upon ESLint's configuration.
>
> We strongly recommend that you do not use the no-undef lint rule on
> TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by
> TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does
> this significantly better.

They recommend to disable no-undef for TypeScript by adding an override to your ESLint configuration like so:

```
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['*.ts'],
    rules: {
      'no-undef': 'off',
    },
  },
],
```